# Cannot access macvlan docker container from another device on network via ip

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, lan, macvlan

I have a docker container I would like to access from other clients on the LAN. I do not want to access them via the docker host's IP and bind container ports to host ports. I would like to access the container via its own IP address as if it was an independent physical device on the LAN itself.

It seems that the `macvlan` network is the way to do this. I created a macvlan network like so:

```
 docker network create -d macvlan \
--subnet=192.168.1.0/24 \
--gateway=192.168.1.1 \
 -o parent=eth0 network_macvlan
```

where `eth0` is the network interface on the host and the `--gateway` IP is pointing to the router's gateway IP. Then in my `docker-compose.yml` file I am declaring the network just created as external, and creating the service:

```
networks:
  network_macvlan:
    external: true

services:
  jellyfin:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/jellyfin:latest
    container_name: jellyfin
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    volumes:
      - /jellyfin-config:/config
      - /Series:/data/tvshows
      - /Movies:/data/movies
    ports:
      - 8096:8096
    networks:
      network_macvlan:
       ipv4_address: 192.168.1.20
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Next I run the service with `docker-compose up -d jellyfin`, and I know the service is correctly assigned the IP address since running `docker inspect network_macvlan` shows:

```
 "Containers": {
            "adcf094a88fe4e70ece4fa8df7e3766605b0edb25da29563": {
                "Name": "jellyfin",
               "EndpointID": "77c533fcd084caf388c91dfe33d1abe8a1f9fb4ba099c10243be4b85e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:14",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.20/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        }, ...
```

**The Problem is that I cannot access this IP address from other clients on the LAN.**

1. `ping 192.168.1.20`: shows `Request timeout for icmp_seq`
2. MAC address not showing up in the router's gateway web app

What am I missing here?

I also tried creating the network on `eth0.50` instead of `eth0` as a [trunked bridge example](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-macvlan/) in the official docs but did not solve the issue.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution?. The closest thing that i got to is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74377630/docker-bridge-network-with-public-ip-addresses-same-level-as-host-machine

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your interface to promiscuous mode. Use:

```bash
ip link set eth1 promisc on
```