# Docker bridge network with public ip addresses (same level as host machine)

Tags: linux, docker, networking

I am trying to create a docker bridge that will assign containers public ips that i want to be resolvable in internet. Let's assume that `192.168.33.0/24` is a public CIDR.

The network configuration is as follows:

```bash
sudo docker network create \
    --driver bridge \
    --subnet=192.168.33.0/24 \
    --gateway=192.168.33.10 \
    --opt "com.docker.network.bridge.name"="docker1" \
    shared_nw
```

the container command

```bash
docker run --name container1 --net shared_nw --ip 192.168.33.11 -dt ubuntu
```

The host can access the `192.168.33.11` container and it's listening ports. But any other client on the outside can't, which makes sense because it's a host only bridge.

So i did the following:

```bash
sudo brctl addif docker1 eth1
```

Which made the containers accessible from the outside, but my docker host was not reachable anymore via  any kind of port (ex: ssh).

Any ideas how to keep the host reachable or is there any way to make the docker bridge accessible from the outside?

Thanks.

Comment: If you remove all of the manual setup you show in the question, and use the `docker run -p` option, the containers will be accessible on all host interfaces on the specified port.  If you have multiple host interfaces then you can `docker run -p host_ip:host_port:container_port` to select a specific one.  Will that approach work for you?

Comment: Yes, it would theoretically work if (you would know before hand what ports to expose, you already know the number of ips(containers) you would need, macvlan allows you to actually use a public CIDR which solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is another driver that does exactly this called `macvlan`. All i had to do is to change the network to:

```bash
sudo docker network create \
    --driver macvlan \
    --subnet=192.168.33.0/24 \
    --gateway=192.168.33.10 \
    --opt parent=ens18 shared_nw
```